# Converted project from VS2008 to VS2013 and can no longer use the Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 or Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 Providers

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013

I have a project that was created in VS2008, and updated to VS2013 recently. I am trying to use the Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0 provider to connect to a MS Excel file and it is throwing the error:

> The 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' provider is not registered on the local
>   machine."** (It throws the same error when I use the
>   Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 provider, except replace the JET with the ACE
>   reference).

However, when I create a brand new project in VS2013 and attempt to use the exact same code that uses these two providers, it works perfectly fine.

I'm running Windows 7 64-bit, with Office 32-bit and Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate 64-bit. Any idea what the difference would be between a new project created in VS2013 and a project that's been converted to 2013 from 2008?

Everything I can find says to set the Application Configuration Platform to x86, but when I do, it causes my project to error when building. I can certainly provide any code snippets that may be useful in assisting.

Comment: A 64-bit version of JET does not exist. You should run your code explicitly in 32-bit mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 provider is not supported in 64-bit environments.

The following is one of several links I found explaining essentially the same information.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/cfb9efe8-4de2-40b6-b817-553c91b9f9c6/the-microsoftjetoledb40-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: I've tried both, JET and ACE. JET  works when I create a new application in VS2013, but not in a previously created app...

Comment: If you are running an app with the JET engine, I'd have to assume it's a 32-bit app running under WOW, not a native 64-bit app. You can't load a 32-bit library into a 64-bit executable.

Comment: You are correct, we are using 32-bit app running under WOW, it is not a native 64-bit app. I am going to attempt to convert it to 64-bit and see what happens. Thanks.

Comment: So, I tried converting to 64-bit, and it did not help. Something interesting though, if I switch from IISExpress to Local IIS (IIS 7) it stops working. If I switch it back to IISExpress, it begins to work again.

Comment: Keep in mind that the older 4.0 JET engine will not run in the 64-bit environment. I'm thinking that may be the loop you're in; something works, but it works because (somehow) it's really running as a 32-bit app; converting it to 64-bit fails because the driver doesn't work in 64-bit mode. You'll need to move to the 64-bit Access Database Driver if you stay in the 64-bit world.

Answer (score 0):

you need to download and install the 64bit version of the Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010.

You can download it from here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255

Comment: This doesn't load because it is a 32-bit version of Excel.